# USB drive shows up as unknown device, but can't be used

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

I've recently gotten a new USB drive, and the problem is, whenever I plug it in, it just shows up as an unknown device. It also won't install the driver. So, basically, I can't use my USB, which is obviously a problem. I've already tried a lot of solutions, and trying to use the troubleshooter promptly gives me an error (sdiageng.dll isn't valid or something). I've tried using the USB with other computers, works perfectly fine. I've got Windows 7 btw.
Thanks in advance.

Note : I'm translating all the window names, like troubleshooter, etc. from Dutch, so bear with me.

Comment: Disconnect drive, run [USB Oblivion](http://code.google.com/p/usboblivion/), reboot and try again. Also, if it's USB-powered, try with both USB plugs (some drives have a Y-type cable). If this helps then most likely your USB port is not supplying sufficient power to run the drive.

Comment: The USB oblivion didn't work.

Comment: Do other USB drives work fine on the same PC?

Comment: No, that's the funny thing, I used to have another usb drive, like, 2gb, can't remember the name, and it worked fine. the USB I'm talking about right now is the Kingston DT 100 G2 16 GB.

Comment: Did you try it on all the USB ports?

Comment: All of them, front, back.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your USB drivers as well as you chipset driver.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: I've already tried updating my drivers, it says that it requires an interactive windows computer (?). Thus resulting in nothing happening. Also, what's a chipset driver?

Comment: Alright, so, figured out with a chipset driver is, updated it, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

YES ! I fixed it.
The trick was to go into devices and printers, and then right click uninstall, reboot, and now it's just in the list of storage, things, in computer.

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out. Since you updated your chipset drivers. The computer would start detecting hardware, after you removed the ghost driver assigned to your USB device Windows will pick up the right one upon restart. Good Job man. :-)